# Firefox Preview Gives Me Blank Page

Tags: html

Coding in Dreamweaver. When right clicking to preview the HTML and CSS in Firefox or Chrome, it gives me a blank page. The `<title>` shows, but that is all.

This is the code for the header:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Goats for Sale | Clayson Ridge Farm
        <!-- Responsive Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 769px)" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 481px)" href="768styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)" href="480styles.css">
        <!-- End Stylesheets -->

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
```

Comment: Could you post code that we can use to replicate your problem?

Comment: Dreamweaver is long, long, long gone and bought out by Adobe. The best I can do is to tell you that it's very likely an issue with your HTML. What's the full HTML for your webpage?

Comment: Is it badly copied or `title` end tag is really missing `</title>`?

Comment: That was it. Geez I'm a knob. Thank you.

Comment: It is ok ;) you're welcome @SereneTheif

Comment: @rlb.usa Dreamweaver is still available through Adobe.

Answer (score 3):

Your title doesn't close.  It should be:

```
    <title>Goats for Sale | Clayson Ridge Farm</title>
```